# EasyHook and communication

Tags: c#, dll, easyhook

Using EasyHook I have set up the following structure:

**APP <--> Interface <--> DLL**

I am trying to run some code inside the injected DLL when I press a button in the APP.

I managed to get the DLL to send messages outside using this code:

```
((EntryPoint)HookRuntimeInfo.Callback).Interface.WriteLine("");
```

But how can I actually make code run inside the injected DLL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure a bi-directional IPC interface. There are a range of different ways to implement this. What follows is one example using .NET Remoting.

First take a look at the EasyHook [remote file monitor tutorial](http://easyhook.github.io/tutorials/remotefilemonitor.html) as a starting point for creating your interface to send messages from the DLL back to APP, i.e. **APP <- interface <- DLL**.

To allow messages from **APP -> interface -> DLL**, a new channel needs to be configured within the DLL [IEntryPoint constructor](https://github.com/spazzarama/Direct3DHook/blob/master/Capture/EntryPoint.cs#L33): e.g.

```
    #region Allow client event handlers (bi-directional IPC)
    // Attempt to create a IpcServerChannel so that any event handlers on the client will function correctly
    System.Collections.IDictionary properties = new System.Collections.Hashtable();
    properties["name"] = channelName;
    properties["portName"] = channelName + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"); // random portName so no conflict with existing channels of channelName

    System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider binaryProv = new System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider();
    binaryProv.TypeFilterLevel = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.TypeFilterLevel.Full;

    System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Ipc.IpcServerChannel _clientServerChannel = new System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Ipc.IpcServerChannel(properties, binaryProv);
        System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(_clientServerChannel, false);
    #endregion
```

To implement the IPC from **APP -> interface -> DLL** take a look at the `Disconnect` method and `Disconnected` event within the "Client-side events" of the [Direct3DHook project](https://github.com/spazzarama/Direct3DHook), `CaptureInterface.Disconnect`, `CaptureInterface.Disconnected` and  `ClientCaptureInterfaceEventProxy.Disconnected`, all in [CaptureInterface.cs](https://github.com/spazzarama/Direct3DHook/blob/master/Capture/Interface/CaptureInterface.cs). In addition to the interface class, this approach also uses a client event proxy class that inherits from `MarshalByRefObject` and allows an event handler to be called elsewhere in your DLL in response to the APP calling a method. You will need to take a good look at the code linked, there are some additional points of interest that need to be considered (such as event handler lifetime), the interface implements a wrapper around each event to trigger it in a "Safe" manner.

Finally the handler for the `Disconnected` event is attached within the DLL's `IEntryPoint` Run method:

```
    _interface.Disconnected += _clientEventProxy.DisconnectedProxyHandler;

    _clientEventProxy.Disconnected += () =>
            {
                // This code in the DLL will run when APP calls CaptureInterface.Disconnect
            };
```

Comment: Wow, I have been reading the D3DHook project for a few days and never quite understood it, but thanks to you I just got it to work! Thank you!!!

Comment: @Eliza glad it helped

Comment: Hi there - thanks for the great answer. Could you elaborate on why the ClientCaptureInferfaceEventProxy is there? Is there any difficulties with simply using the original interface for those event handlers?

Comment: @Tom'Blue'Piddock the handler must inherit from MarshalByRefObj, I found it easier to use a proxy class for this otherwise you can run into issues with your other non-marshal compatible types.